# I want to show mobile menu on sm at <=768px.I am using navbar-expand-md so it will show mobile menu on sm screens <768px

Tags: html, css

Here is my css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  


  .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
      left: -75%;
      transition: height 0s ease;
      background-color: white;
  }

  .navbar-collapse.show {
      left: 0;
      transition: left 300ms ease-in-out;
      background-color: white;
  }

  .navbar-toggler.collapsed ~ .navbar-collapse {
      transition: left 500ms ease-in-out;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    position: fixed;
   
    top:85px;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
   
    
}

  
}
```

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>   
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
<header style="background-color:#F4DF4EFF;" class="sticy-top">
  <div class="container" >
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light sticky-top">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="nav-main" >
        
        <?php
          $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
          $custom_logo_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id ,  'full' );
          $custom_logo_url = $custom_logo_data[0];
        ?>  
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $custom_logo_url );  ?>" 
        alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) );  ?>" 
        style="width:80px;height:70px;"   />
        <!-- <span ><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x "  ></i></span> -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01"  >
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <div style="color:black;">
            <?php
              wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'footer-menu' ,
                'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto', 
                    
              ) );
            ?> 
          </div>  
          </ul>
          
       </div>
        
       
     
      </div>
   </nav>
  </div>
</header
```

I want to show mobile menu on sm at <=768px ..But i get mobile menu at <768.. (or)As i am using navbar-expand-md so that nav bar collpase at <768px but i want it to collpase at <=768px and slide navbar from left at <=768.. I think i want to do some modifications in my css and code to get the result.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hey put @media (max-width: 767.98px) in media screen according to bootstrap breakpoint.

Comment: When you put your code into your question (as code, not an image) please show enough relevant CSS. The image provided so far does not show all the possibilities for the CSS at different  viewport settings.

Comment: if i change @media (max-width: 767.98px) in media screen ..there is no result..Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace the class name `navbar-expand-lg` instead of `navbar-expand-md` in header.php on line number 23.

Comment: if i change the  class name navbar-expand-md to navbar-expand-lg the navbar toggle will collapse at <992 but i want it to collpase at <=768 and menu is swipe from left to right

Comment: If possible can you upload the project to the demo server and share the link? so I can help you to find the issue

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16Lj0o4RNA9EuQFin2Jf16_Ec6KvVMKLe?usp=sharing

Comment: Please help me team

Comment: PLEASE CAN ANYONE HELP ME ..TO RESOLVE THE ISSUE